# Is there a node called Spline Parameter in Blender 3.0?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I have been doing some tutorials in geometry nodes, and I see this node in the tutorials, but I don't see them in the list.  **Curve Parameter** is the closest node as far as I can tell.  Does spline parameter exist?

Comment: I don't know for that particular node, but Geometry Nodes being somewhat new and still vastly in initial development, you can easily have such issues where nodes change names,  places, or got completely removed. There has been a substantial amount of changes done in GN for Blender 3.0. And you also have the issue that many people got the "bright" idea to make tutorials on development builds, which by design are prone to change all the time and are most likely to be outdated. Your safest bet is to at least make sure to watch a tutorial made on the same Blender version as yours.

Comment: Related: [Can't find the node! Which node is available in which Blender version?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/273541)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Spline parameter* is found in 3.1 and replaces *curve parameter* as of this writing. You can find more details [here](https://developer.blender.org/D13275) for the specific changes to the node (it is not yet added to the manual). To summarize, the change is to add an Index output that contains the index of each control point on the given spline.

3.0 files will potentially open in 3.1 with an undefined node (although it appears that sometimes blender automatically converts it) and the *curve parameter* would need to be replaced by *spline parameter* and vice versa.